# Best way to populate db with large ruby/json files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rake

Let's say I have a ruby or json file consisting of hashes and range anywhere from 14-20MB (300K lines unminified). I've created a rake task which loops through each hash and creates an AR object based on the values in each hash.

Unfortunately due to the file's size I get `stack level too deep` errors each time I run the task. The only way I've actually gotten the script to run is by splitting the file into smaller ones. Although this works, it gets extremely tedious to split the file and repeat the task over and over. Are there any good alternatives for loading/running large files?

**Rake Task**

```
namespace :db do
  task populate: :environment do
    $restaurants.each_with_index do |r, index|
      uri = URI(r[:website])

      restaurant = Restaurant.find_or_create_by(name: r[:name], website: "#{uri.scheme}://#{uri.host}")

      restaurant.cuisines = r[:cuisines].map { |c| Cuisine.find_or_create_by(name: c) }

      location = Location.create(
        restaurant: restaurant,
        city_id: 1,
        address: r[:address],
        latitude: r[:latitude],
        longitude: r[:longitude],
        phone_number: r[:phone_number]
      )

      r[:hours].each do |h|
        Hour.create(
          location: location,
          day: Date::DAYNAMES.index(h[:day]),
          opens: h[:opens],
          closes: h[:closes]
        )
      end

      menu_group = MenuGroup.create(
        restaurant: restaurant,
        locations: [location],
        address: r[:address]
      )

      r[:menus].each do |m|
        menu = Menu.create(
          menu_group: menu_group,
          position: m[:position],
          name: m[:name]
        )

        m[:sections].each do |s|
          section = Section.create(
            menu: menu,
            position: s[:position],
            name: s[:name]
          )

          s[:dishes].each do |d|
            tag = Tag.find_or_create_by(
              name: d[:name].downcase.strip
            )

            Dish.find_or_create_by(
              restaurant: restaurant,
              sections: [section],
              tags: [tag],
              name: d[:name],
              description: d[:description]
            )
          end
        end
      end

      puts "#{index + 1} of #{$restaurants.size} completed"
    end
  end
end
```

**Error**

```
rake aborted!
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:12:in`to_binary'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:12:in`input_to_storage'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:37:in`fetch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/compile_cache/iseq.rb:37:in`load_iseq'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:21:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:65:in `register'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:20:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:29:in `require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `block in require'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:283:in `require'
/Users/user/app/lib/tasks/populate.rake:1:in `<main>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/bootsnap-1.3.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:50:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `block in load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:249:in `load_dependency'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/activesupport-5.2.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:277:in `load'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `block in run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:650:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/application.rb:515:in `run_tasks_blocks'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/railties-5.2.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:459:in `load_tasks'
/Users/user/app/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/rake-12.3.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

Comment: That's a weird one. I can't really help you here, but hopefully someone else will be able to.

Comment: The error "stack level too deep" is not caused by files being too big (and let's be honest: 20MB is not very big). "Stack level too deep" means the chain of methods being called (`a` calls `b`, `b` calls `c`, `c` calls `d`, ...) is too long. Typically this is caused by infinite recursion—`d` calls `a`, which calls `b` again, and so on. That's not apparent in your stack trace, but it might be revealed in the full trace (`--trace`). Since the error is happening in the `bootsnap` code, you might also try uninstalling that gem temporarily to see if the error goes away.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. Just as a test I commented out any model related code but still got the error. Sucks because bootsnap is required for any/all rake related tasks. Provided the full trace if that helps at all.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Complex-Job-Workflows-with-Batches) to break the jobs in to workers that can run concurrently.

For example:

```
$restaurants.each_with_index do |r, index|
    RestaurantParser.perform_async(r, index)
end
```

In RestaurantParser perform the steps you would normally take.

As long as restaurants don't rely on other restaurants already existing in the DB you can run workers concurrently to speed up the process.